# Know the flow before an event on Google Analytics

Tags: google, google-analytics

I'm using Google Analytics to know which path flow one user has used before converting in paying users.

Actually I'm simply calling (i.e to track when user buy some package):

```
ga('send', { hitType: 'event', eventCategory: 'package', eventAction: 'bought'});
```

Now my doubt is how can I know which path flow the user has done before this event?

i.e > visited homepage > visited pricing page > bought package.

At the moment I'm using section Audience > User report with a custom segment with the event to track buy package.

Is this the right way to do what I want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is the Goal Flow along with Conversion reports.. This method allows you to track all users moves up to the Goal set up by you. It can also report other the sites a user came from based on your Goals and User flow within Conversion Reports.

You can read more at Google
https://support.google.com/analytics/topic/1631741

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to track which keywords instead of seeing "not provided" ? Can I set some custom vars from referals?

https://www.evernote.com/l/AObA4Tf-lxJL7bowM1Vb424DffzamXHu43I

From what I understand this come from an organic search and the user landed on the homepage. Right?